# Lubuntu 16.04 wifi not working on Dell inspiron 14 3452

Tags: networking, 16.04, lubuntu, dell

I installed Lubuntu 16.04 on a Dell inspiron 14 3452 everything seems fine except the wifi isnt working.

Its saying there isnt a network device.

I saw on a forum that someone got it to work by disabling secure boot but that trick isnt working.

There is no ethernet port. So i cant do any updating.

Thanks in advance to who ever can help out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: It didnt out put anything.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the command carefully? It is case sensitive. In case you are sure, please post the output of `lspci` command.

Comment: And also check that the Wi-Fi is not disabled in BIOS.

Comment: I didnt use caps on net or a3 so i just retyped it and it still didnt show anything but lspci showed a few things. Ill have to type this out. host bridge, vga compatible controller, sd host controller,  usb controller, encryption controller, audio device, ISA bridge, SMBus. All of it intel corp device

Comment: You need to use caps in `Net` and `A3`. If it shows nothing, it means that most likely there is no wireless device there, or it is disabled in BIOS. Is anything regarding "Network" in `lspci` output?

Comment: Theres no option in the bios for disabling it.

Comment: Try to reset BIOS to defaults. And you do not need to retype. You can save the text to a file and then post it from some other device.

Comment: Its easier to type it all up.

Comment: I had already tried reseting the bios.

Comment: It is not easier to type it. Anyway if there is no wireless device in `lspci`, nothing can be done.